# How to make java application as windows service?

Tags: java, windows-services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a windows service from java app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68113/how-to-create-a-windows-service-from-java-app)

How to make the Java application as windows service? I need to run the Java application as windows service for all PC in my company whichever connected to the server. How is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you will have to use the "Java Service Wrapper".

Here is a link that I think can help you with that: http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/introduction.html#service

**Update**

Another 2 links:

[How to use Java Service Wrapper for our java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539212/how-to-use-java-service-wrapper-for-our-java-application)

http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/qna-service.html

Answer (score 2):

Procrun is a set of applications that allow Windows users to wrap (mostly) Java applications (e.g. Tomcat) as a Windows service.

http://commons.apache.org/daemon/procrun.html

Answer (score 2):

I always you `Winrun4J` for windows service, I think it more simple than Java Service Wrapper
But for Linux I use `Java Service Wrapper`.

http://winrun4j.sourceforge.net/